# haskell indentation issue with do and let ..in statements

Tags: haskell, indentation

I tried various combinations to fix the indentation for the following code but failed. How shall i fix the below

```
fold' list = do
    let result = foldl (+) list
    in putStrLn $ "Reduced " ++ show(result)
    return $ result

 parse error on input `in'
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: `let` bindings in `do` blocks don't need an `in`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a **`do` clause**, the **`in` keyword should not be used**.

So you can fix it with writing:

```
fold' list = do
    let result = foldl (+) list
    putStrLn $ "Reduced " ++ show(result)   -- no "in" keyword
    return $ result
```

The scope of the `let` statement is the rest of the clauses.

The translation is like specified in [*section 3.14 of the Haskell report* [link]](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html):

> ```
> do {e}                =   e
> do {e;stmts}          =   e >> do {stmts}
> do {p <- e; stmts}    = let ok p = do {stmts}
>                             ok _ = fail "..."
>                         in e >>= ok
> do {let decls; stmts} =   let decls in do {stmts}
> ```

So in case we define two `let` statements with the same name (which is *not* recommended), the first one moving to the top will count.

So for:

```
foo = do
    let x = "4"
    putStrLn x
    let x = "2"
    putStrLn x
```

It will translate into:

```
foo = let x = "4" in (putStrLn x >> (let x = "2" in putStrLn x))
```

So the first `putStrLn` will use the `x` defined by `let x = "4"` whereas the last one will use the `x` defined in `let x = "2"`.